# C# Versioning API controllers when using Mediator

Tags: c#, mediator

We would like to version our C# API controllers and there are a few options which are fine to go with such as

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
Public AccountController : ControllerBase
```

or on specific endpoints with the same annotation.

The problem we have is that our controllers use Mediator so how to do make breaking changes to the Mediator Commands/Requests in a version controlled way? Do we pass the version number to ALL Mediator methods and make code paths within them? Do we duplicate any broken Mediator methods?

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetInfoRequest());
return Ok(result);
}

[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetInfoRequestV2());
return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Well, the logic behind changes, so the code must be different. So in my opinion what makes sense to create separate handler class for new code. So V2 endpoint would get "new code" in new handler, so, naturally, I would create "V2 handler", exactly as you did.